# R Script coming back with a few errors when scraping basic page

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

Here is my script:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)


link = "http://www.mmadecisions.com/decisions-by-judge/"
page = read_html(link)

name = page %>% html_nodes("#page1 a") %>% html_text()
name_links = page %>% html_nodes("#page1 a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("http://www.mmadecisions.com/", ., sep="")

get_decisions = function(name_link) {
  judge_page = read_html(name_link)
  date = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
  event = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_text()
  fight = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list~ .list+ .list a") %>% html_text()
  decisions = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
  return(judge_page)
}

decision = sapply(name_links, FUN = get_decisions)

judges = data.frame(name, date, event, fight, decision, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The errors I keep getting are as follows:

```
> library(rvest)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> 
> link = "http://www.mmadecisions.com/decisions-by-judge/"
> page = read_html(link)
> 
> name = page %>% html_nodes("#page1 a") %>% html_text()
> name_links = page %>% html_nodes("#page1 a") %>%
+   html_attr("href") %>% paste("http://www.mmadecisions.com/", ., sep="")
> 
> get_decisions = function(name_link) {
+   judge_page = read_html(name_link)
+   date = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
+   event = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_text()
+   fight = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list~ .list+ .list a") %>% html_text()
+   decisions = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
+   return(judge_page)
+ }
> 
> decisions = sapply(name_links, FUN =  get_decisions)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.
Called from: open.connection(x, "rb")
Browse[1]> 
> judges = data.frame(name, date, event, fight, score, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Error in data.frame(name, date, event, fight, score, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  object 'score' not found
```

My goal has been to navigate from a parent page to multiple subpages, scrape four columns of data 'judge-decisions', then print into columns. I appreciate any insight anyone can give on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure about why you have two end variables. If you want a final df of those 4 columns, from each page, you can use `purrr::map_dfr`, and ensure you return a `tibble` from your function. For the connection issue, you need to trim your urls of whitespace.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

link = "http://www.mmadecisions.com/decisions-by-judge/"
page = read_html(link)

name = page %>% html_nodes("#page1 a") %>% html_text()
name_links = page %>% html_nodes("#page1 a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("http://www.mmadecisions.com/", ., sep="") %>% trimws()

get_decisions = function(name_link) {
  judge_page = read_html(name_link)
  tibble(
    date = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text(),
    event = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_text(),
    fight = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list ~ .list + .list a") %>% html_text(),
    decisions = judge_page %>% html_nodes(".list:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
  ) -> t
  return(t)
}

df <- map_dfr(name_links, get_decisions)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am actually just learning R and following a tutorial, trying to replace my values in for the ones in the tutorial. Your code shows no errors, but I am not sure how to utilize the purr::map_dfr to show a table. In my version I would just type view(name) and it would show me - are there any tutorials you recommend for learning this function? Thanks again!

Comment: `View(df)` will show you the _table_. `map_dfr` basically applies the function which returns `tibble`s and maps all those `tibble`s into a single `DataFrame`. I read about it here: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html